# How to read byte correctly from file using Java RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I have a binary file with the byte 88 (which is 136 decimal).

I'm using Java's RandomAccessFile class and the "read" method to read this byte via a pre-defined buffer. I also tried "readUnsignedByte()" but get the same issue as below.

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(inputFile, "r");
byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[32];
randomAccessFile.read(headerBuffer);
```

The code above gives me -120 for 88, not 136.

I realize that the high-order bit or whatever is set, but I still need to be able to read the file and either get 88 or 136.

The issue is that this byte is the offset into the binary file where I can find the first record so a negative number won't work.

Would appreciate suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: What problem did you have with `readUnsignedByte`?

Comment: Does the header-format define a _constant position_ (offset) for your _record-pointer_ (i.e. byte with hex-value `88`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just do `b & 0xFF` to convert it to positive integer.

Comment: You could explain your code? It's not obvious what symbol `b` references, nor does the bit-wise inexperienced know what masking with `& 0xFF` effects 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Byte.toUnsignedInt` method to convert a `byte` into an `int` in an "unsigned" way.

```
jshell> byte b = (byte) 0x88;
b ==> -120
jshell> Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);
$57 ==> 136
```

The operation is the same as `b & 0xff` but doesn't invoke magic numbers or knowledge about bitwise operators.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue with bulk-read

The method [`read(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read(byte[])) you use for reading multiple bytes at-once actually reads a **signed byte** as in [`readByte()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readByte()). Thus you're right, the *first bit* represents the **sign** and will thus be interpreted by Java potentially leading to negative number.

#### Use offset and read unsigned

Benefit of **random-access** is to jump to the position/offset in file using [`seek(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)).
So, if you know the exact position of that *record-pointer* byte, you can jump there and proceed reading the desired byte *as unsigned* using [`readUnsignedByte()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readUnsignedByte()).

#### See also

[How can I read a file as unsigned bytes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144080/how-can-i-read-a-file-as-unsigned-bytes-in-java)